# how can i generate a diagram from a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

i am trying to generate a rails diagram from a project with railroad.
but i am getting a
railroad: command not found
even after installing the plugin : sudo gem install roadrail
what is the problem?
is there an alternative to that plugin?
thank you for you help

Comment: What is your platform?
Also, can you access other commands from gems such as the rails command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install, the command is:

```
sudo gem install railroad
```

not roadrail. Verify that the gem is installed by

```
sudo gem list railroad
```